# How can I add/sum all of the database column according to inputted employeeid and startdate to enddate in ASP MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Good day! I just want to know how to add/sum all the values in a specific database column based on their inputted in a textbox StartDate and EndDate? Textbox "daysworked" only shows the sum according to the sum of the value and EmployeeId but not according to the StartDate and EndDate. I want to display the sum of a specific database column according to their EmployeeId, StartDate and EndDate.

This is my View where I created script that will post my sum and employeeid.

```
@using PayrollWeb.Models
@model PayrollWeb.Models.PayrollFormModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddOrEdit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEdit", "Payroll", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return SubmitFormPayroll(this)" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <h1 style="text-align: center;"><span class="fa fa-calculator"></span>&nbsp;Payroll</h1>
    <br />
<div class="panel-group col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Employee Details
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EmployeeId, new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EmployeeId, Model.Employees, "", new { @class = "form-control" , @id="employeeid"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmployeeId, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.StartDate, new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartDate, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "startdate", @type = "date" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StartDate, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EndDate, new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EndDate, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "enddate", @type = "date" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EndDate, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PayDate, new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PayDate, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "datepickertodin", @type = "date" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PayDate, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PayFrequency, new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PayFrequency, new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "BI-WEEKLY", @readonly = "readonly" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PayFrequency, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.DaysWorked, new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DaysWorked, new { @class = "form-control", @id="daysworked" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DaysWorked, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.MonthlyRate, new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MonthlyRate , new { @class = "form-control", @id="monthlyrate"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.MonthlyRate, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        @*<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SalaryPerDay, new { @class = "form-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SalaryPerDay, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "salaryperday" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.WorkDays, new { @class = "form-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.WorkDays, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "workdays" })
            </div>*@
    <div class="panel-group col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Income
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.BasicPayAmount, new { @class = "form-label" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BasicPayAmount, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "basicpayamount" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.BasicPayAmount, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="panel-group col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Deductions
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.WitholdingTax, new { @class = "form-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.WitholdingTax, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.WitholdingTax, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PagibigContribution, new { @class = "form-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PagibigContribution, new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "100.00", @readonly = "readonly" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PagibigContribution, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PhilhealthContribution, new { @class = "form-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PhilhealthContribution, new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "191.25", @readonly = "readonly" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PhilhealthContribution, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SSSContribution, new { @class = "form-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SSSContribution, new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "560.00", @readonly = "readonly" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SSSContribution, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Deduction, new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Deduction, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "deduction" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Deduction, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox()" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-top: 25px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="TextBoxContainer" style="margin-top: 6%;   ">
                <!--Textboxes will be added here -->
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CashLoan, new { @class = "form-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CashLoan, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CashLoan, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-group col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Summary
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.TotalSalary, new { @class = "form-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TotalSalary, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "totalsalary" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TotalSalary, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Payroll")"><span class="fa fa-backward"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Back to Dashboard</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
            var div = $("<div />").attr("class", "row").attr("style","margin-top: 6px;");

            var textBox = $("<input />").attr("type", "textbox").attr("name", "DynamicTextBox").attr("style", "width:30%;margin-left:5%;");
            textBox.val(value);
            div.append(textBox);


            var textBox1 = $("<input />").attr("type", "textbox").attr("name", "DynamicTextBox1").attr("style", "width:30%;margin-left:5%;");
            textBox1.val(value);
            div.append(textBox1);

            var button = $("<input />").attr("type", "button").attr("value", "Remove").attr("style", "width:20%;margin-left:5%;");
            button.attr("onclick", "RemoveTextBox(this)");
            div.append(button);

            return div;

        }
        function AddTextBox() {
            var div = GetDynamicTextBox("");
            $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
        }

        function RemoveTextBox(button) {
            $(button).parent().remove();
        }



         $('#employeeid').change( function () {
             var employeeid = $(this).val();
             //var startdatedata = $('#startdate').val();
             //var enddatedata = $('#enddate').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "@Url.Action("LoadDetails", "Payroll")",
                data: {
                    employeeid: employeeid,
                    //startdatedata: startdatedata,
                    //enddatedata: enddatedata
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#employeeid').val(data.EmployeeId);
                    //$('#startdate').val(data.StartDate);
                    //$('#enddate').val(data.EndDate);
                    $('#daysworked').val(data.DaysWorked);
                }
            });
         });

        @*$(function () {
            var values = eval('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Values)');
            if (values != null) {
                $("#TextBoxContainer").html("");
                $(values).each(function () {
                    $("#TextBoxContainer").append(GetDynamicTextBox(this));
                });
            }
        });*@
                //$(function () {
                //    $('#datepickerto').datepicker({ //datepicker startdate
                //        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
                //        changeMonth: true,
                //        changeYear: true,
                //        showOn: "both",
                //        buttonText : "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>"
                //    });
                //});
                //$(function () {
                //    $('#datepickertodin').datepicker({ //datepicker enddate
                //        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
                //        changeMonth: true,
                //        changeYear: true,
                //        showOn: "both",
                //        buttonText: "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>"
                //    });
                //});

                //$(function () { //calculate

                //    $("#salaryperday,#workdays,#deduction").keyup(function (e) {

                //        var salary = $("#salaryperday").val();
                //        var work = $("#workdays").val();
                //        var deduction = $("#deduction").val();
                //        var result = "";

                //        if (salary !== "" && work !== "" && deduction !== "" && $.isNumeric(salary) && $.isNumeric(work) && $.isNumeric(deduction)) {
                //            result = parseFloat(salary) * parseFloat(work) - parseFloat(deduction);
                //        }
                //        $("#totalsalary").val(result);

                //    });

                //});

                $(function () { //calculate

                    $("#monthlyrate").keyup(function (e) {

                        var monthlyrate = $("#monthlyrate").val();
                        var result = "";

                        if (monthlyrate !== "" && $.isNumeric(monthlyrate)) {
                            result = parseFloat(monthlyrate) / 2;
                        }
                        $("#basicpayamount").val(result);

                    });

                });
    </script>
}
```

And this is my PayrollController where I have my LoadDetails function where my linq.

```
using PayrollWeb.DB.Core;
using PayrollWeb.DB.Data;
using PayrollWeb.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace PayrollWeb.Controllers
{
    public class PayrollController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Payroll
        private PayrollwebContext db = new PayrollwebContext(); //connection
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult GetData()
        {
            var payrolls = (from p in db.Payrolls.ToList()
                            join e in db.Employees.ToList() on p.EmployeeId equals e.Id

                            select new PayrollListModel
                            {
                                Id = p.Id,
                                EmployeeName = e.FirstName + " " + e.MiddleName + " " + e.LastName,
                                StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(p.StartDate),
                                EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(p.EndDate),
                                Deduction = p.Deduction,
                                TotalSalary = p.TotalSalary
                            });
            return Json(new { data = payrolls.ToList() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult AddOrEdit(int? id)
        {
            var model = new PayrollFormModel();

            if (id != null)
                model.Id = Convert.ToInt32(id);

            model = PreparePayrollFormModel(model);

            return View(model);
        }

        //[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddOrEdit(PayrollFormModel model, string[] DynamicTextBox, int[] DynamicTextBox1)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            ViewBag.Values = serializer.Serialize(DynamicTextBox);
            ViewBag.Values = serializer.Serialize(DynamicTextBox1);

            //bool returnloop = false;

            //foreach (string textboxValue in DynamicTextBox) //category
            //{
                //foreach (int textboxValue1 in DynamicTextBox1) //amount
                //{
                    using (var db = new PayrollwebContext())
                    {
                        if (model.Id > 0)
                        { // update
                            var EmployeePayroll = db.Payrolls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);

                            EmployeePayroll.Id = model.Id;
                            EmployeePayroll.EmployeeId = (int)model.EmployeeId;
                            EmployeePayroll.StartDate = model.StartDate;
                            EmployeePayroll.EndDate = model.EndDate;
                            EmployeePayroll.PayFrequency = model.PayFrequency;
                            EmployeePayroll.PayDate = model.PayDate;
                            EmployeePayroll.DaysWorked = model.DaysWorked;
                            EmployeePayroll.MonthlyRate = model.MonthlyRate;
                            EmployeePayroll.WitholdingTax = model.WitholdingTax;
                            EmployeePayroll.PagibigContribution = model.PagibigContribution;
                            EmployeePayroll.PhilhealthContribution = model.PhilhealthContribution;
                            EmployeePayroll.SSSContribution = model.SSSContribution;
                            //EmployeePayroll.SalaryPerDay = model.SalaryPerDay;
                            //EmployeePayroll.WorkDays = model.WorkDays;
                            EmployeePayroll.Deduction = model.Deduction;
                            EmployeePayroll.CashLoan = model.CashLoan;
                            EmployeePayroll.TotalSalary = model.TotalSalary;

                            db.Payrolls.AddOrUpdate(EmployeePayroll);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Updated Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                        }
                        else
                        { //insertion

                            var payrolls = new Payroll
                            {
                                EmployeeId = (int)model.EmployeeId,
                                StartDate = model.StartDate,
                                EndDate = model.EndDate,
                                PayFrequency = model.PayFrequency,
                                PayDate = model.PayDate,
                                DaysWorked = model.DaysWorked,
                                MonthlyRate = model.MonthlyRate,
                                BasicPayAmount = model.BasicPayAmount,
                                WitholdingTax = model.WitholdingTax,
                                PagibigContribution = model.PagibigContribution,
                                PhilhealthContribution = model.PhilhealthContribution,
                                SSSContribution = model.SSSContribution,
                                //SalaryPerDay = model.SalaryPerDay,
                                //WorkDays = model.WorkDays,
                                Deduction = model.Deduction,
                                CashLoan = model.CashLoan,
                                TotalSalary = model.TotalSalary
                            };
                            db.Payrolls.Add(payrolls);

                         List<Deductions> list = new List<Deductions>();
                         for (int i = 0; i < DynamicTextBox.Length; i++)
                         {
                                var deduct = new Deductions
                            {
                                EmployeeId = (int)payrolls.EmployeeId,
                                Category = DynamicTextBox[i],
                                Amount = Convert.ToInt32(DynamicTextBox1[i]),
                            };
                          list.Add(deduct);

                         }
                    db.Deductionss.AddRange(list);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
              }
            model = PreparePayrollFormModel(model);
            return View(model);
        }

        public PayrollFormModel PreparePayrollFormModel(PayrollFormModel model) //model null
        {
            model.Employees = db.Employees.Select(x => new SelectListItem //laman ng dropdown
            {
                Text = x.FirstName + " " + x.MiddleName + " " + x.LastName,
                Value = x.Id.ToString()
            });




            if (model.Id > 0) //edit din to para magreturn ng value
            {
                var payroll = db.Payrolls.Find(model.Id); //null

                model.EmployeeId = payroll.EmployeeId;
                model.StartDate = payroll.StartDate;
                model.EndDate = payroll.EndDate;
                //model.SalaryPerDay = payroll.SalaryPerDay;
                //model.WorkDays = payroll.WorkDays;
                model.Deduction = payroll.Deduction;
                model.TotalSalary = payroll.TotalSalary;

                model.Employees = db.Employees.Select(x => new SelectListItem //laman ng dropdown
                {
                    Text = x.FirstName + " " + x.MiddleName + " " + x.LastName,
                    Value = x.Id.ToString()
                });
            }
            return model;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(PayrollFormModel model)
        {
            if (model.Id > 0)
            {
                var orders = db.Payrolls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);
                db.Payrolls.Remove(orders);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { success = true, message = "Deleted Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult LoadDetails(int employeeid, DateTime? startdatedata, DateTime? enddatedata)
        {
            //var getEmployee = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == employeeid); // nakuha ko na dito yung id ni customer
            //var getAttendace = db.Attendances.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeId == getEmployee.Id);
            //var getPayroll = db.Payrolls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeid);
            //example lang to aa depende sayo kung decimal ba or int or var

            decimal? sum = db.Attendances
                                .Where(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeid)
                                 //&& x.Date >= startdatedata &&
                                 //x.Date <=  enddatedata)
                                .Sum(x => x.Overtime);


            var LoadDetails = new PayrollFormModel
            {
                EmployeeId = employeeid,
                //StartDate = startdatedata,
                //EndDate = enddatedata,
                DaysWorked = sum,
            };
            return Json(LoadDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone will help me. Thank you in advance. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = db.Attendances.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeid && x.Date >= startdatedata && x.Date <= enddatedata).Sum(y => y.Overtime)
```

Should be fine. If there are any error try .Where().ToList().Sum()

Comment: Thank you for your answer but where is the 'y => y.Overtime ' came from?

Overtime is from Attendances DBSet also.

Comment: You need to sum of employees by what ? What is the formula ?

Comment: Sum of all column in Overtime according to employeeid and startdate and enddate

Comment: I didnt understand meaning of "Sum of all columns". Are you try to say Grouping dataset by employeeId,startDate and endDate ?

Answer (score 0):

I already figure out what's wrong with my code. I'll just change this

```
    decimal? sum = db.Attendances
                        .Where(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeid)
                         //&& x.Date >= startdatedata &&
                         //x.Date <=  enddatedata)
                        .Sum(x => x.Overtime);
```

to this:

```
    decimal? sum = db.Attendances
                        .Where(x => x.Date >= startdatedata &&
                         x.Date <= enddatedata && x.EmployeeId == employeeid)
                        .Sum(x => x.Overtime);
```

Thank you!